# Home screen widget layouts with same aspect ratio after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, widget, orientation, tablet

I want my widget maintain the same aspect ration after rotation in tablets

In my Manifest I call the layout in the receiver:

```
android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:resource="@layout/mywidget"
```

I make two folder in res: layout-land and layout-port and i put in both the same file "mywidget.xml" but with different values (rows & columns) to tray reach the same aspect ratio:

For landscape:

```
<appwidget-provider 
android:minWidth="250dip" 
android:minHeight="460dip">
</appwidget-provider>
```

For portrait:

```
<appwidget-provider 
android:minWidth="320dip" 
android:minHeight="390dip">
</appwidget-provider>
```

But landscape don't work. I can put any value and noting happen. Only make effect change values in the portrait file. But impossible to obtain the same aspect ratio.
Help for a solution.

Comment: AFAIK, the decision regarding the aspect ratio is up to the home screen, not you. Your widths and heights get converted into a certain number of cells, and those cells do not have to be square or otherwise consistent between orientations.

Comment: I understand.  But is not possible to  compensate this conversion for example adding more vertical cells (in dip value)? Note: my widget is vertical and I want to maintain it vertically in landscape orientation.

Comment: Not reliably. First, cells are large (e.g., my home screen has a 5x6 grid of cells). Second, cells do not have to be square. Overall, the behavior of home screens, when it comes to orientation, varies by the home screen. Some might not reload widget metadata based on an orientation change. Please note that `<appwidget-provider>` elements go in `res/xml/` and related directories, not `res/layout/`.